# C++ returning a char pointer and printing

Tags: c++, pointers, char, cout

Is this correct? I have a pointer that I'm passing into a void function, and then I want to overwrite

```
void Foo(char *myReturn)
{
   char myOutput[] = "Foobar";
   myReturn = myOutput;
}
int main()
{
   char *myTestVar;
   Foo(myTestVar);
   cout << myTestVar;
}
```

This just crashes with no error log.

Now I have tried `myReturn = &myOutput` as well as `*myReturn = &myOutput` (which is how I thought it worked that way unless Im misunderstanding something) but I always get

```
:|error: invalid conversion from 'char (*)[(((unsigned int)(((int)length) + -0x000000001)) + 1)]' to 'char'|
```

Comment: Your `main` uses `()` around its body, not `{}`

Comment: Thanks haha my mistake when typing the question. Not the actual issue though ( I wish )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myOutput[]` is a local variable in the function `foo()`. You assign the address of `myOutput` to `myReturn` :

```
myReturn = myOutput;    // myReturn & myOutput have same address
```

The function is then finished and `myOutput` gets deleted. `myTestVar`, which you passed to the function `foo()`, is now pointing to an invalid memory location. That's why you get the error.
Try this:

```
myReturn = new char[strlen(myOutput)+1];
strcpy(myReturn, myOutput);
```

`myReturn` and `myOutput` have same values but `myReturn` is pointing to a different memory address than `myOutput`.

Comment: that also crashes with
Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minutes, 3 seconds)

Comment: Yes, it should. myReturn = new char[] means that you allocate a new memory for it i-e different from myTestVar. So, when your program comes to the line cout<<myTestVar; you are actually trying to print an invalid memory location. The solution is easy, return myReturn from Foo() and assign to myTestVar. Now again they are both pointing to the same location.

Comment: So there really isn't a way to do it without having a return from the void function?

Comment: Yes there are, by using array i-e pass by reference. or by pointers.
For pointers, allocate memory to myTestVar and then just copy the string into myOutput in the Foo() function. It will do the job but you will be facing the problem of giving 'size' to myTestvar because you don't know what length of string is going to be copied in it.

Answer (score 4):

`myOutput` is local to `Foo` and does not have any memory allocated on the heap. So when you try to access it through `myTestVar`, it does not point to a valid memory location and trying to access data through it crashes you program.

Comment: You can use strcpy to copy the string.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong because `char myOutput[]` is allocated using the [automatic storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) which means that it will get deleted when it goes out of scope. Therefore, If you do use it outside of the function then you are invoking [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I see now, thank you. I figured it was something glaringly obvious I was overlooking. The scope of functions keeping variables in memory gets me every time.

So in this case, how would you recommend returning storing information to *myReturn like the char[] "foobar"?

Answer (score 1):

Your program has a **undefined behavior**. `myOutput[]` is a local array with automatic storage and it  does not exist beyond the scope of the function.